# EXCEL Formula_How to do different things according to the content of the cell

Tags: excel-formula

Good morning, I'm working on a table (report) of quality control. And for doing the statistical analyse, I'd like to calculate the averange or the number of Good result of several tests' result. For exemple:

```
item    | test   | result1 | result2 | result3
piece 1 | colour | Good    | Good    | NoGood
piece 1 | length | 1,1     | 1,12    | 1,2
piece 2 | colour | Good    | Good    | Good
piece 2 | length | 1,2     | 1,21    | 1,1
```

And I've used :

`=IF(Isnumeric(C2:E2);F2;Average(C2:E2))`

to calculate the averange of the numerical result (like length), and that works well. But I wish that it can count the number of "Good" and show me the answer too. Like:

```
item    | test   | result1 | result2 | result3 | statistic
piece 1 | colour | Good    | Good    | NoGood  | 2
piece 1 | length | 1,1     | 1,12    | 1,2     | 1.14
piece 2 | colour | Good    | Good    | Good    | 3
piece 2 | length | 1,2     | 1,21    | 1,1     | 1.17
```

So I've tried :

`=OR(IF(Isnumeric(C2:E2);F2;average(C2:E2));IF(COUNTIF(C2:E2,"*Good*")))`

But It's not good. So if you know how to correct if or even better, you've got a more practical method, please leave a comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use a formula like : `=IF(B2="colour";COUNTIF(C2:E2;"good");AVERAGE(C2:E2))`

This will produce the following output:

ps.: i use my excel in pt_br, thats why it has `se`, `cont.se` and `média` instead of `if`, `countif` and `average`.

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thank you it works well, and if I have the third criteria, like weight, can I put it into the IF?

Comment: Since weight is a number too, the same formula will work! It checks if column B is equal 'colour', and if so, it will count the number of 'good' words, otherwise it will calculate the average. But if you need to add another criteria, you can use `NESTED IF's` like `=IF(criteria, value_true, IF(criteria, value_true, value_false)` ... but if you nest a lot, it will become hard to understand. [see here](http://ccm.net/faq/26886-nesting-more-than-7-if-statements-in-an-excel-function). If you need more criteria, try spliting the analysis columns into analysis_colour, analysis_length, and so on...